# R - Finding all possible combinations

Tags: r

I try to get all possible combinations of the vector.
There is an example:

```
test <- c("A","B","C","D") 
expand.grid(test,test) 

   Var1 Var2 
1     A    A  
2     B    A 
3     C    A 
4     D    A 
5     A    B 
6     B    B 
7     C    B 
8     D    B 
9     A    C 
10    B    C 
11    C    C 
12    D    C 
13    A    D 
14    B    D 
15    C    D 
16    D    D
```

but I need to get only unique "transactions" (without the duplicated letters in one row), i.e. I would like to get such output:

```
   Var1 Var2  
2     B    A
3     C    A
4     D    A
5     A    B
7     C    B 
8     D    B 
9     A    C 
10    B    C 
12    D    C 
13    A    D 
14    B    D
15    C    D
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `subset` i.e. `subset(expand.grid(test,test) , Var1 != Var2)` or with `tidyverse` `crossing(test, test) %>% filter(test != test1)`

Comment: Maybe `combn(test, 2)` ?

Comment: thanks!!! I have another small question,   If I would have more than 2 vectors: Do I need to write so? <br> subset(expand.grid(test,test,test) , ( any (
                                            (Var1 != Var2)||
                                            (Var1 != Var3)||
                                            (Var2 != Var1) 
                                                )))

Comment: Feel free to try it and see! It's usually much quicker to try something on your own than asking us if it's okay.